# How to avoid duplicate values in joining two or three tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have this two tables and I want to join their two ID's.

```
Household Info                             
1
2
3

Household Members
1
1
1
2
3
3
3
3
3
```

The values is repeating over and over again, as you have noticed on my screenshot. The output I want is, I want a query of this:

```
Household Info.HID                Household Members.HID
1                                 1
                                  1
                                  1
2                                 2
3                                 3
                                  3
                                  3
                                  3
                                  3
```

[image]

Since in the Table Household Info there are only 3 HID while the table Household Members there are **three:1, one:2, and five:3**

Hope you can help me on this one :3 
EDITED: I am using **Microsoft Access** as RDBMS

Comment: Could you show the query you try so far?

Comment: You're confusing an issue of data storage and retrieval with one of data display. The latter is normally handled in application level code (e.g. a simple PHP loop

Comment: Have you tried with mohan111 post. Is that you are looking at

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I just tried simple query, UNION, DISTINCT. I have not tried complicated queries... But they aren't coming up with the output that I seek.

Comment: @Strawberry I just want to display "how many members of the family that are associated with the household head"

Comment: @StackNewUser yes I did, but I can't get it working...

Comment: That's not what your question says

Comment: @Strawberry it might not be, but on the description that I stated above, I meant for that... Because when I use **"Natural,equi,full join, or even distinct"** I can't get the output that I desire :X And btw, I just tried simple queries, but I can't get it running. I mean I don't get my desired output.

Comment: Fine, but it still isn't clear what you actually want as a result.

Comment: @Strawberry, please check I edit it, that should be clear by now..

Comment: The query for "how many members of the family are associated with the household head" and the query for the original question are obviously different. Either delete the comment, or edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

For an RDBMS which supports CTE...

```
DECLARE @Household  TABLE 
    ( Household  VARCHAR(10))
;

INSERT INTO @Household
    ( Household )
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3)
;


declare @HouseholdMembers TABLE 
    ( HouseholdMembers  VARCHAR(10))
;

INSERT INTO @HouseholdMembers
    ( HouseholdMembers )
VALUES
    (1),
    (1),
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (3),
    (3),
    (3),
    (3)
;

Select 
CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Household ELSE '' END Household,
HouseholdMembers 
from (
select h.Household,
hm.HouseholdMembers,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY hm.HouseholdMembers ORDER BY h.Household)RN from @Household h
LEFT JOIN @HouseholdMembers hm
ON hm.HouseholdMembers = h.Household)T
```

Comment: You are a man of few words ;) some explanation would be useful for him.

Comment: I tried the code you stated, but it seems that I can't get it working..

`WITH CTE AS (
select h.HID,hm.HID,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY hm.HID ORDER BY h.HID)RN from [Household Info] h
LEFT JOIN [Household Members] hm
ON hm.HID = h.HID)
select CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN h.HID ELSE '' END h.HID,hm.HID from CTE`
I tried any possibilities, but I really can't get it working. It seems that's a bit complicated query :3

Comment: @mohan111 My RDBMS doesn't support **CTE** I am using **Microsoft access** I can't get my desired output :X

Comment: @mohan111 [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286417/mysql-join-return-null-for-duplicate-results-in-left-table) <------- This might be the output that I am looking for, but I can't get it working....

Comment: I have modified code by removing CTE and used Derived Column

Comment: [Here is the error](http://i.imgur.com/vAsE3Yf.png) Yes I saw that, and I tried, but It is still not working.... [Here is the error](http://i.imgur.com/vAsE3Yf.png) @mohan111

Comment: @mohan111 http://i.imgur.com/vAsE3Yf.png And also checked the comment below the "EDIT 2" by sir Vanko.. That's the output I desire..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what are you using as RDBMS.

I think that you can use pivot for your case:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

or to use grouping:

```
select c2, c3
  , sum( case when no_of_days <= 7 then 1 else 0 end) as dlt8
  , sum( case when no_of_days between 8 and 14 then 1 else 0 end) as d8to14
  , sum( case when no_of_days between 15 and 21 then 1 else 0 end) as d15to21
  , sum( case when no_of_days between 22 and 27 then 1 else 0 end) as d22to27
from mytable
group by c2, c3
order by c2, c3;
```

Here you can find similar answer to your question:

[Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by)

**Edit 1**

If you need something like this:

```
SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Mary
1               John
1               Sam
2               Alaina
2               Edward
```

Result I expected was:

```
SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Mary, John, Sam
2               Alaina, Edward
```

you can check this example:

[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

**Edit 2**

And the last option that I can remember is this one. It's for MySQL but you can reuse the logic:

[MySQL JOIN - Return NULL for duplicate results in left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286417/mysql-join-return-null-for-duplicate-results-in-left-table)

Comment: I don't think so, or it is just I don't know? I am really having hard time here. I don't think pivot can solved this kind of problem :3

Comment: maybe you need something closer like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: The edit 2, might be the one that I am looking for, but I can't get it working :((

`select 
  case when rownum = 1 then title else null end HID,
  HID,
  [Member Name]
from
(
  SELECT c.HID, 
    i.HID, 
    i.Member Name,
    @row:=(case when @prev=HID and @precat=[Member Name] 
           then @row else 0 end) + 1 as rownum,
    @prev:=HID ptitle,
    @precat:=[Member Name] pcat
  FROM [Household Members] AS i
  INNER JOIN [Household Info] AS c 
    ON c.hid = i.Member Name
   order by i.Member Name, c.HID
) src
order by [Member Name], rownum`

**PLEASE HELP :3**